# Как убрать расстояние между текстом и границами блока?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно как-то убрать этот промежуток (отмечен красными стрелками)?

Comment: поищи инфу о reset.css

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что за вредная привычка любые проблемы ресетом затыкать

Comment: А промежуток вероятно меняется через line-height

Comment: @andreymal потому что потом появятся очередные промежутки но уже в другом месте. Не проще ли сразу сделать как хочется?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему вы решили, что промежутки в другом месте это плохо? Почему вы решили, что автору их не хочется? Обратите внимание, что на скриншоте виден margin: 8px у body - но автор на него не жалуется

Comment: @andreymal пока что не жалуется. Почему - потому что новичок и не знает нюансы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения этой проблемы нужно воспользоваться свойством line-height. Оно задаёт высоту строк, в которых располагается текст.

```
<div class="example">
  NEW ARRIVALS
</div>
```

```
.example {
  font-size: 40px; /* Высота шрифта */
  line-height: 42px; /* Высота строк */
  padding: 0px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

Результат:

[image: line-height и font-size]

Однако если сделать line-height = font-size, то промежутки всё равно останутся.

Согласно [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/css/font-size), на самом деле

> размер шрифта определяется как высота от базовой линии до верхней границы кегельной площадки,

поэтому, чтобы убрать интервалы, надо записать line-height меньше, чем font-size:

```
.example {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: yellowgreen;
}
```

Результат:

[image: line-height < font-size]

Comment: огромное спасибо!!