# Как убрать лишнее простарнство в блоке заголовка?

Tags: html, css, h2

В проекте имеется заголовок"ЭТО ПРОСТО!". Мне нужно, чтобы высота блока совпадала с высотой букв. Как это сделать?

Код: `<h2 class="title-big">ЭТО ПРОСТО!</h2>`
[image: пример]

Comment: Я уже когда-то отвечал на подобный вопрос. Возможно, это вам поможет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431022/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5

Comment: обнулите вертикальные padding & margin(-top, -bottom) у h2. если этого будет мало, так же обнулите у его родителя и т.д.